# joining 2 const char*s c++

Tags: c++, string, char, string-concatenation

How can I combine two const char*s into a third?

i'm trying to do this with this code:

```
const char* pName = "Foo"
printf("\nMy name is %s.\n\n\n",pName);
const char* nName;
int num_chars = asprintf(&nName, "%s%s", "Somebody known as ", pName);
```

But I get this error:

```
'asprintf': identifier not found
```

I include stdio.h via this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: More of a C question, but did you mean `sprintf`? Also, you only pass one string where it expects two.

Comment: You've tagged this C++. Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: What compiler on what platform are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple, just use C++:

```
const char* pName = "Foo"
std::string name("Somebody known as ");
name += pName;

const char* nName = name.c_str();
```

Comment: @user1100671: You should be informed though, that the `const char*` is only valid as long as the `std::string` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

`asprintf` is a GNU extension. You can instead use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), or
 [`strncat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat), but you'll need to handle the memory management yourself: `asprintf` allocates the result for you.

Better to use `std:string`, which will make the code much easier.

Comment: Weird, never heard of `asprintf`. Looks interesting enough.

Comment: If you use `std::string`, you can get const char* from it via `std::string::c_str()` function.

Answer (score 2):

sprintf(snprintf) or strcat(strncat).
sprintf.

```
sprintf(nName, "%s%s", "Somebody known as ", pName);
```

strcat.

```
strcpy(nName, "Somebody known as ");
strcat(nName, pName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are using C, besides that you've tagged this question as C++. If you want C++, see Luchian's answer.

There are few errors in the code - the bigger error is that you didn't allocated memory for string pointing by `pName`. Second error is that you are taking address of the `nName` variable, and not the address of reserved memory location in you `asprintf` function. Third error is that `asprintf` function is no standard C function, but the GNU extension and it might not be available on your compiler (you didn't say which is): http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf

You should use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char* pName = "Foo"
printf("\nMy name is %s.\n\n\n",pName);
char nName[30];
int num_chars = sprintf(nName, "%s%s", "Somebody known as ", pName);
```

**Edit**: I've read more about asprintf function now. You should pass address of your pointer in `asprintf`, but it should not be `const char *` but the `char*`, as memory location it points will change after allocating enough memory in `asprintf`.